# how to access iPhone camera correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iphone, camera

I want to access the mobile camera or webcam through Javascript. I got it working fine for webcams and android devices. When testing on iPhone X iOS 15.6, I only get a **black screen**, no matter if i choose front or rear camera. The console says
`Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.`
The popup for the permission comes up and I grant it. I also tried to change permissions for Safari generally to **allow** but it doesn't change a thing.

Any clues anyone?

Here is the code for the Camera component. using react 18.1.0

```js
export const MemeCam = ({
  setShowCam,
  handleUpload,
  hasWeb3,
  isConnected,
  mobileCamera
}) => {
  const videoRef = useRef(null);
  const photoRef = useRef(null);
  const [img, setImg] = useState();
  const [imgFile, setImgFile] = useState();
  const [topText, setTopText] = useState("");
  const [bottomText, setBottomText] = useState("");
  const [facingMode, setFacingMode] = useState();
  const [effectiveCameraHeight, setEffectiveCameraHeight] = useState(0);
  const [effectiveCameraWidth, setEffectiveCameraWidth] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!mobileCamera) {
      setFacingMode("user");
    } else {
      const facingMode = mobileCamera === "front" ? "user" : "environment";
      setFacingMode(facingMode);
    }
  }, [mobileCamera]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!facingMode) {
      return;
    }

    const getUserCamera = () => {
      navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({
          video: {
            width: effectiveCameraWidth,
            height: effectiveCameraHeight,
            facingMode: facingMode
          },
          audio: false
        })
        .then((stream) => {
          let video = videoRef.current;
          let stream_settings = stream.getVideoTracks()[0].getSettings();
          setEffectiveCameraHeight(stream_settings.height);
          setEffectiveCameraWidth(stream_settings.width);
          video.srcObject = stream;

          video.play();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    };

    getUserCamera();
  }, [videoRef, facingMode, effectiveCameraHeight, effectiveCameraWidth]);

  if (
    !("mediaDevices" in navigator && "getUserMedia" in navigator.mediaDevices)
  ) {
    return null;
  }

  const handleImageSave = (canvasReference) => {
    if (!photoRef) return null;
    canvasToImage(canvasReference, {
      name: "custom name",
      type: "png",
      quality: 0.5
    });
  };
  const handleSnapshot = () => {
    let width = effectiveCameraWidth;
    let height = effectiveCameraHeight;
    const photo = photoRef.current;
    const video = videoRef.current;

    photo.width = width;
    photo.height = height;

    let ctx = photo.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);
    const image = new Image();
    image.src = photo.toDataURL("image/png");
    image.onload = () => setImg(image);
  };

  const writeToCanvas = (event) => {
    const text = event.target.value;
    const field = event.target.name;
    const canvas = photoRef.current;
    const width = canvas.width;
    const height = canvas.height;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
    ctx.font = "20px Comic Sans MS";
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    if (field === "topText") {
      ctx.fillText(text, width / 2, 20);
      ctx.fillText(bottomText, width / 2, height - 10);
    }
    if (field === "bottomText") {
      ctx.fillText(topText, width / 2, 20);
      ctx.fillText(text, width / 2, height - 10);
    }
    setImgFile(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
  };

  const dataURLtoFile = (dataurl, filename) => {
    var arr = dataurl.split(","),
      mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
      bstr = atob(arr[1]),
      n = bstr.length,
      u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);

    while (n--) {
      u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
    }
    return new File([u8arr], filename, { type: mime });
  };

  const canMint = hasWeb3 && isConnected;

  return (
    <StyledMemeCam
      cameraWidth={effectiveCameraWidth}
      cameraHeight={effectiveCameraHeight}>
      <div className="title">
        {" "}
        Use the Meme of the Day MemeCam and generate your own personal Meme!
      </div>
      <div className="cheeze-close-btn-wrapper">
        <ButtonStandard
          onClick={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            handleSnapshot();
          }}
          label={!img ? "CHEEZE!" : "RETAKE!"}
        />
        <ButtonStandard
          onClick={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            window.location.reload();
          }}
          label="CLOSE MEMECAM!"
        />
      </div>
      <video ref={videoRef} className={img ? "hide-me" : "video"}></video>

      <canvas ref={photoRef} className={!img ? "hide-me" : "canvas"} />
      {img && (
        <div className="inputs">
          <div className="inputs-fields">
            <Input
              name="topText"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Top Text"
              value={topText}
              onChange={(e) => {
                setTopText(e.target.value);
                writeToCanvas(e);
              }}
            />
            <Input
              name="bottomText"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Bottom Text"
              value={bottomText}
              onChange={(e) => {
                setBottomText(e.target.value);
                writeToCanvas(e);
              }}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="inputs-buttons">
            <ButtonStandard
              onClick={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                handleImageSave(photoRef.current);
              }}
              label="Save Image"
            />
            {canMint ? (
              <ButtonStandard
                onClick={(e) => {
                  e.preventDefault();

                  console.log({ imgFile });
                  const newFile = dataURLtoFile(imgFile, "newmeme.png");
                  console.log({ newFile });
                  handleUpload(newFile);
                }}
                label="MINT!"
              />
            ) : (
              "Please connect with Web3 to mint!"
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
      <div className="description">
        <p>Simple take a snapshot and add your own text.</p>
        <p>Then Mint it!</p>
        <p>You can also download your Meme and save it for later.</p>
        <p>We hope you enjoy the Meme of the Day MemeCam</p>
        <p>
          Please feel free to reach out and give us your feedback about this
          feature!
        </p>
      </div>
    </StyledMemeCam>
  );
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: [any of these?](https://www.google.com/search?q=user+denied+permission+ios+camera+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Looked through this link @mplungjan, it does not quite fit with my situation. The app will ask for permission but the iPhone does not seem to accept the allow choice.